# How to remove jank when setting an element to a fixed position using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a webpage that when scrolled down, the text freezes when it reaches the last paragraph of text but the images keep on scrolling. I've got the implementation working but there is a lot of jank when scrolling with a mouse wheel, not so much if I click and drag the scroll bar.

Are there any optimizations I can make to this code to make work as intended or is there a different way to accomplish the same task?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(keepTextStationary);
    //keepTextStationary(); // Less janky, but still horrible
});

function keepTextStationary() {

    var textRect = writtenContent.getBoundingClientRect();
    var imageRec = images.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (textRect.bottom < window.innerHeight && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {

        writtenContent.style.position = 'relative';
        writtenContent.style.bottom = (225 - document.documentElement.scrollTop) + 'px';

        if (imagesTop === undefined) {
            imagesTop = imageRec.y;
        }

    } else {
        writtenContent.style.bottom = (225 - document.documentElement.scrollTop) + 'px';
    }

    if (imageRec.y >= imagesTop) {
        writtenContent.style.position = '';
    }
}
```

Here is the site so you can see the problem.
https://bowerbankninow.azurewebsites.net/exhibitions/oscar-perry-the-pheasant

Comment: Please include full working code example with your question. Your JS snippet is hard to test without knowing HTML and CSS around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are causing layout trashing every time you call `getBoundingClientRect`. Try debouncing your scroll events:

```
var lastScrollY = 0;
var ticking = false;

function keepTextStationary() {

    var textRect = writtenContent.getBoundingClientRect();
    var imageRec = images.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (textRect.bottom < window.innerHeight && lastScrollY > 0) {

        writtenContent.style.position = 'relative';
        writtenContent.style.bottom = (225 - lastScrollY) + 'px';

        if (imagesTop === undefined) {
            imagesTop = imageRec.y;
        }

    } else {
        writtenContent.style.bottom = (225 - lastScrollY) + 'px';
    }

    if (imageRec.y >= imagesTop) {
        writtenContent.style.position = '';
    }

    ticking = false;
}

function onScroll() {
    lastScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    requestTick();
}

function requestTick() {
    if (!ticking) {
        requestAnimationFrame(keepTextStationary);
        ticking = true;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll );
```

See this article for in-depth explanation: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

Answer (score 0):

You dont.

Relocations / styling in javascript take place after the CSS has been loaded. Bad practise. What you can do, is make it animated to make it look less horrible.

Why is pure CSS not an option ?

Comment: I'm not saying CSS is not an option, in my question I've actually asked if there's a better way to do it. Perhaps you can provide a code sample?